# How to convert nested Lists into a single List in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, flatten

Below is the list details:

```
my_list = ['If', 'FirstNumber', ['is', 'greater', 'than'], '12.9']
```

Using this above mentioned my_list details I need to get output like below.

```
my_list1 = ['If', 'FirstNumber', 'is', 'greater', 'than', '12.9']
```

I have tried using a for loop but I did not get the expected result.

```
my_list = ['If', 'FirstNumber', ['is', 'greater', 'than'], '12.9']
for i in my_list:
    t2=i
    print(t2)
```

The actual result I am getting is :

```
If
FirstNumber
['is', 'greater', 'than']
12.9
```

The expected result should be given as below:

```
my_list1 = ['If', 'FirstNumber', 'is', 'greater', 'than', '12.9']
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
my_list1 = [] 
for i in my_list: 
    if isinstance(i,list): 
        my_list1.extend(i) 
    else: 
        my_list1.append(i)
```

Comment: Your welcome @Basav. please consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers